# Different runtimes using parameter vs. constant

Tags: sql-server

A strange thing is happening to me during execution a specific query.

I have this query:

```
DECLARE @P0 as varchar(4000)
DECLARE @P1 as varchar(4000)

SET @P0 ='P0'
SET @P1 ='2015-02-21 00:00:00'

Select DISTINCT  top 10 USER_ID, MODULE_TYPE_CLASS, ADDRESS
From VIA_MESSAGE_AGGREGATOR ma
where state = @P0
and DATE_CREATED <= @P1
```

This take a long to execute (about 23 seconds).

When I substitute the @P0 for 'AA' value the same query is executed in 3 secs.

This is strange because I have an index with the same columns (`state` and `date_created`) and when I execute with parameters the index is not used, but when I execute with the `'AA'` value instead of parameter then SQL Server uses the index.

Anyone have any idea why its behaves like this? I'm using JPA to execute this queries, the code is just an example of the same behavior.

Comment: Can you include the execution plan?

Comment: Is `DATE_CREATED` a `VARCHAR(4000)` in the database? Is `state` a `VARCHAR(4000)`?

Comment: Google "parameter sniffing." Add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the statement to see if the problem disappears. Also, see if JPA is setting explicit types for the parameters - e.g. is it using `VARCHAR(2)` for the value `'AA'`? Finally, why is `@P1` a string and not a datetime? Even more finally, `DISTINCT TOP` and no `ORDER BY`?

Comment: No DATE_CREATED is a varchar(19) and STATE is varchar(4).

Comment: With OPTION (RECOMPILE) the problem disappears. But i can´t put the hint into the JPA. @P1 is a String because of architecture decisions. The varchar(4000) is the JPA that puts but even if i run with the correct type the performance is poor. About the order by, yes you are correct but the performance is only a bit better.

Comment: ***WHY*** is `DATE_CREATED` not a proper `DATE` datatype?? Please always use the **most appropriate** datatype - and for a date - that's `DATE` but certainly **not** a `VARCHAR` type!

Comment: You are missing the point! Forget that this is a DATE and this is a String, because the input that resides inside the column is a String and not a DATE. The problem is the @P0 parameter, because of it is that the index is not used. The reason is WHY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

After further analysis and following the recommendation of  Aaron Bertrand and google "parameter sniffing" i found what is causing this its the SQL Server.

This is the "normal" behavior of the SQL Server, and the queries must be analysed and changed individually to resolve its problems.

Here is the link for the best description of what is happening to me:

[Parameter Sniffing](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/)

Hope this help, as it help me.

Cheers,

Bigster